# Connecting SharePoint 2010 Announcement Lists to Outlook

Tags: list, outlook, announcements

I am trying to connect an announcement list to outlook and the connect to outlook button is grayed out.  I spoke to my admin and she doens't seem to know how to correct this problem

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this to happen. Which browser are you using? Are you using IE 8, 9, 10 32 or 64 bit? 64-bit has many problems with this.

Tryo to access to Internet Options --> security tab --> then, under Internet zones unchech Enhanced protected mode. Restart the browser

However, not all the lists get synchronized properly with Outlook (as Calendar or Tasks). Check this article for more information: [Sync content with outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/synchronize-sharepoint-2010-content-with-outlook-2010-HA101881295.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is the browser as I have the same problem but only on a list of announcements which appear to be a different type of list in sharepoint. I can happily link to Outlook on other lists from the same browser (64 bit Chrome or Edge) but not on any announcement list the link to outlook button is grayed out.